# checking the availability of file information of the file loaded in input type="file"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, modernizr

I had created a plugin that were showing image thumbnail and information before uploading the Image but as it is using html5 features well it doesn't work with old IE versions. I'm just trying do update this plugin to tell the user yo update his browser or use another browser if the features are not supported. here is the part of the code that was reading image (fired on onchange event of the file input ):

```
function readImg() {
                $('#preview').html('<br /><span>Preview</span><br />');
                var file = document.getElementById('addfile').files[0];
                if (file.size > 1048576) {
                    parent.$('<div></div>').html('Photo file must be at most 1MB!').alertBox({ title:  'Upload Photo' });
                    document.getElementById('addfile').value = '';
                    return;
                }
                ldimgext = desiredExt(file.name);
                if (!ldimgext) {
                    parent.$('<div></div>').html('Only gif,jpg and png files are accepted!').alertBox({ title: 'Upload Photo' });
                    document.getElementById('addfile').value = '';
                    return;
                }
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imgLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }

function imgLoaded(e) {
                tsimg = e.target.result.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg|gif);base64,/, "");
                var img = $('<img src="'+ e.target.result + '"/>');
                var tmp = new Image();
                tmp.src = e.target.result;
                tmp.onload = function () {
                    if (tmp.width > tmp.height) img.attr('width', '80'); else img.attr('height', '80');
                    $('#preview').html('').append(img);
                }
```

How can I check If FileReader and filesize, ... all Options I used here are supported in browser or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on change event of the element you can check to see if the `size` is supported by checking the returned value of your `file` variable, if it is `null` then it is not supported. so your code would end up being:

```
function readImg() {
                $('#preview').html('<br /><span>Preview</span><br />');
                var file = document.getElementById('addfile').files[0];

                //the added part
                if(file==null){
                    alert('your browser does not support this feature');
                    return false;
                }

                if (file.size > 1048576) {
                    parent.$('<div></div>').html('Photo file must be at most 1MB!').alertBox({ title:  'Upload Photo' });
                    document.getElementById('addfile').value = '';
                    return;
                }
                ldimgext = desiredExt(file.name);
                if (!ldimgext) {
                    parent.$('<div></div>').html('Only gif,jpg and png files are accepted!').alertBox({ title: 'Upload Photo' });
                    document.getElementById('addfile').value = '';
                    return;
                }
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imgLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }

function imgLoaded(e) {
                tsimg = e.target.result.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg|gif);base64,/, "");
                var img = $('<img src="'+ e.target.result + '"/>');
                var tmp = new Image();
                tmp.src = e.target.result;
                tmp.onload = function () {
                    if (tmp.width > tmp.height) img.attr('width', '80'); else img.attr('height', '80');
                    $('#preview').html('').append(img);
                }
```